# List of posts not generating correct `post.url` link for Jekyll, Github Pages site

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I want to create a very simple jekyll site hosted on GH pages. However, I can't seem to get it to work. I am not using Jekyll directly and am using GH for all of the coding actually.

My directory is as follows:

```
_config.yml
index.md
/_posts
    2021-12-31-post.md
```

My `_config.yml` file simply consists of one line:

```
theme: jekyll-theme-minimal
```

I simply want the index home page to display links to all of the posts. As such, I added this snippet to `index.md` directly taken from Jekyll's documentation:

```
<ul>
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This correctly displays list of posts on the index page. However, the links are broken. For example, when clicking the link given for the singular post, it goes to `username.github.io/2021-12-31-post/` which won't work because my repository is named, for example, as `blog`. When I manually type `username.github.io/blog/2021-12-31-post/`, the post shows.

So I guess this boils down into `post.url` not giving the correct link.

How could I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Needed to prepend `base.url` to the link:

```
href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}"
```

and add the `baseurl` in the config file.